# Robot seems to ignore map, using TEB and custom-made map

Tags: navigation, mapping, ros-melodic, map-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all, I am running melodic and using the TEB local planner. I am having an issue with my use of a custom-made map. It seems that the robot "ignores" the map boundaries and I am not sure what I am missing.

Currently, I have a move_base.launch file, which loads a global_costmap (global frame=odom and robot_base_frame=base_link), local_costmap (global_frame=odom and robot_base_frame=base_link), costmap_common, and base_local_planner (odom_topic=odom and map_frame=map) and it includes a base_local_planner (TEB) and controller_frequency.

I run a map_server with a simple pgm that is a 240 x 400 map @ 0.010m/cell and I run rviz to visual the robot and custom map.

However, when the robot goes to a position using TEB, the robot_description (the visualization of my robot) goes over the custom map and I'm pretty sure it is just not registering those boundaries.

Any advice or anything I could be missing? Let me know if you need any other info. I tried to attach an image of the rviz but I need more points apparently :P

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/343023/robot-seems-to-ignore-map,-using-teb-and-custom-made-map/) by [sekarkulandaivel](https://answers.ros.org/users/51358/sekarkulandaivel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2020-01-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

it could be the case that you didn't register the static map in the config file: local_costmap_params.yaml
please check out [this thread](https://answers.ros.org/question/255220/is-it-normal-behavior-for-local-planners-to-ignore-static-obstacles-if-no-pointcloud-or-laserscan-data-is-being-published/) for more information. Hope it helps!

---

Originally posted by [YB17](https://answers.ros.org/users/52001/yb17/) with karma: 16 on 2020-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0